# Where do I add my authorization token when making a request to the YouTube v3 Data API?

Tags: python, python-requests, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm currently using the Python Requests module to add videos to a playlist created by me. On the docs for `playlistItems.insert`, it says authorization is required with one of three possible scopes. I have created an OAUTH2.0 credential token in my project's credential panel and set the scope correctly. Currently I'm trying to pass the credential as follows:

```
payload = {
    'access_token': [My Client ID],
    'part': 'snippet'}
new_vid = requests.post(f'{base_url}playlistItems', params=payload)
```

When executing the code, I get the following error message:

```
"message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project."
```

Am I passing the authorization token in the correct place, or should I be passing it somewhere else in the `POST` request?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the Authorization token as a header parameter. Check the example below:

```py
import requests

headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}

params = (
    ('key', '[YOUR_API_KEY]'),
    ('part','snippet')
)

response = requests.post('https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems', headers=headers, params=params)
```

Comment: I have added the headers argument, using the Client ID from the google dev console in the place of YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN. I still get a 401 response expecting an authorization token. Is this the wrong token to use as the access token? I have the Client ID type set as desktop since it's running from a command line.

Comment: You need an API Key and an OAuth token in order to fulfill your task. Please check this link to get an idea on how to generate the credentials: https://developers.google.com/youtube/registering_an_application